# save input on button click from the footer.html.rb rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have _footer.html.rb file in the Shared folder. I do have an email input field and button. I want user on click to save the email to the database.

this is _footer.html.rb

```
   <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
    <h5 class="text-uppercase">Subscribe Today</h5>
    <p>Get our newsletter and stay current on rental deals and specials..</p>
    <div >
      <div style="text-align: -webkit-center; padding-bottom: .9rem;">
        <input id="email" placeholder="Your Email" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 28rem;"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" label="Subscribe" type="button"><span class="btn__label">Subscribe</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

this is models subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
end
```

is there is a way to save the email with create a controller.rb for the _footer . cause i might have them else where as well like in the _navbar and _footer?

Comment: you can write actions in the application controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a controller action to proceed user's input.

Assume you have this in routes

```
post 'subscriptions', to: 'subscriptions#create', as: :subscriptions
```

```
def create
   Subscription.create(email: params[:email]
   render :js => "alert('Thank you for subscribing');"
   # or
   # create `app/views/create.js.erb` file and comment above `render` statement 
end
```

Then, wrap inputs in `form` with option `remote: true` to make an Ajax call

```
<%= form_tag(subscriptions_path, remote: true) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email  %>
    <%= button_tag 'Subscribe', type: 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```